# No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured in SWAGGER

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, swagger

I have been trying to solve this issue since forever.
When I try to debug an endpoint from my swagger it doesn't seem to hit the controller and instead "No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured" error message is being displayed. I checked my aws setting the regionendpoint is set as "us-east-1". it has been configured and I have the access. I dont know why this issue is arising. Can anybody help.

Also, I am able to debug other endpoints it is only this other endpoint that doesnt hit the controller.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. The .aws/credentials files wasn’t being read.